# How can i use for loop in lambda or any one line function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, one-liner

I have a task to transform this code to one line and I really dont know how to do it. I couldnt find anything that solve this problem.

Here's the code:

```
def rowsub(mat, row1, row2, factor):
   for i in range(len(mat[row2])):
      mat[row2][i] -= factor * mat[row1][i]
```

I know its not helps in any way to do it a one line but thats my task. If someone can help I would be glad

Im using python 3.7

Comment: Does the whole *definition* need to be a single line, or just the body of the function?  And where is the *lambda* your title speaks of?

Comment: You can use the functools package with the `reduce` function for this kind of task: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce "Reduce" is helpful when you are repeatedly making modifications to one variable for each input in an iterable.

Comment: `mat[row2] = [i - factor * j for i, j in zip(mat[row2], mat[row1])]` If you can use list comprehension.

Comment: thank you very much ssp, your code is working very well for me. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `i in range(i in len(mat[row2]))` you can just use `i,num in enumerate(mat[row2])` to get the index value of the number to i and the value of the number to num.

```py
def rowsub(mat, row1, row2, factor):
    mat[row2]=[ num-factor*(mat[row1][i]) for i,num in enumerate(mat[row2])]
```

To write this oneliner I used [generator expressions](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-generator-expressions/) in which you can create a list of values in a single line.